# Android : Rating bar in View pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, vertical-alignment, ratingbar

I want to achieve layout depicted below . For this I already visit so many links for customization of rating bar but they provide customization in terms of  background , width ,height . For the alternate option I can use Check box group but my priority is **rating bar** in **vertical position** which is on **view-pager** .Any suggestion is appreciable.
Thanks in advance .[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set rating bar in 180 degree to add following code in to XML file.
android:rotation="180", its displaying rating bar in vertical direction.

Answer (score 1):

Put Ratingbar in your PagerAdapter row file & in your xml set property of ratingbar to **rotation -90**

Comment: Thanks brother , i did the same thing but forget to update my answer .The  solution was quite simple and its the same as you suggest.